# how to avoid to use sys.exc_clear

Tags: python, exception, flask, sys

Here is my code:

```
import sys

class App(object):

    def __enter__(self):
         return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, tb):
         print sys.exc_info()

app = App()

with app:

    try:
        1/0
    except:
        print  'Caught you'
        #sys.exc_clear()
```

and another example using flask app context:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.teardown_appcontext
def teardown(exception):
    print exception


with app.app_context():

    try:
        1 / 0
    except:
        pass
```

It's weird that if i didn't call sys.exc_clear when i handle exception, then when exiting app, sys.exc_info will still return exception info.

Is there any way to avoid this case?

In my project which is based on flask,  i will rollback transaction when there is a exception. Although i handled exception, app context can still get it using sys.exc_info like code below showed:

```
#AppContext pop method

def pop(self, exc=None):
    """Pops the app context."""
    self._refcnt -= 1
    if self._refcnt <= 0:
        if exc is None:
            exc = sys.exc_info()[1]
        self.app.do_teardown_appcontext(exc)
    rv = _app_ctx_stack.pop()
    assert rv is self, 'Popped wrong app context.  (%r instead of %r)' \
        % (rv, self)
    appcontext_popped.send(self.app)
```

I cannot ask everyone in my team to call sys.exc_info when handling every single one exception.

How should i do to avoid this situation?

Comment: When you handle an exception, `sys.exc_info()` is cleared when the frame is cleared. You don't need to clear it explicitly. I cannot reproduce your claim that it isn't cleared by the time the appcontext is popped.

Comment: In other words, when the `with` statement is done, `sys.exc_info()` is already cleared for you. If it doesn't for you, then you have a version of Python with a bug. I cannot reproduce the issue in 2.7.8.

Comment: Sorry. Maybe i didn't describe in the right way. I'll create a gist to show how it happened.

Comment: The effects i want is when __exit__ executes, the sys.exc_info is empty, since i have handled it in except statement.

Comment: But `sys.exc_info()` is cleared by the time you get to the `AppContext.pop()`, so I am still not clear why you need that. In the context manager `__exit__` method the `exc_type`, `exc_value`, and `tb` arguments are `None`, so you know the exception has been handled already.

Comment: I changed the question with an flask app example. In this example, the teardown still get exception. When i debuged, the parameters to __exit__ method all are None,  but AppContext use sys.exc_info in its pop method and still got a exception. Maybe i used app in a wrong way. I'll try do read flask source code.

Comment: Of *course* the app context sees the exception; the exception happened within the `with` statement frame, so the exception is still active. Move to a different frame to handle the exception in that case. This is not a common occurrence however.

Comment: I learned to use app context from this [page]( http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/appcontext/)。 In fact, i encounter this problem not in a view but a script which need app context。 I have fixed this problem using a decorator called transactional which will decorator every view and catch exception and rollback. My teardown function now just close db connection. Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is really a bug in how the AppContext handles your case.

The exception is automatically cleared the moment the current frame exits (so outside the `with` statement). If you called another function from within the `with` statement frame and handled the exception there, the `sys.exc_info()` information would be cleared again when that other function exits.

The `AppContext.__exit__()` method is correctly notified that you handled the exception and passes the exception value on to the `AppContext.pop()` method.

As such the Flask `AppContext.pop()` method should use a *different* sentinel value to detect that no exception was passed in; it could detect that `None` was passed in not as a default but as an actual value, indicating no exceptions were raised or were properly handled.

I've [filed an issue with the project](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/issues/1392) requesting that this is implemented, with [accompanying pull request](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/pull/1393). This was merged and will be part of a future release of Flask.

You could use a monkeypatch to backport this to the current Flask version:

```
from flask import app, ctx
import sys

if ctx.AppContext.pop.__defaults__ == (None,):
    # unpatched
    _sentinel = object()

    def do_teardown_appcontext(self, exc=_sentinel):
        if exc is _sentinel:
            exc = sys.exc_info()[1]
        for func in reversed(self.teardown_appcontext_funcs):
            func(exc)
        app.appcontext_tearing_down.send(self, exc=exc)

    app.Flask.do_teardown_appcontext = do_teardown_appcontext

    def pop(self, exc=_sentinel):
        """Pops the app context."""
        self._refcnt -= 1
        if self._refcnt <= 0:
            if exc is _sentinel:
                exc = sys.exc_info()[1]
            self.app.do_teardown_appcontext(exc)
        rv = ctx._app_ctx_stack.pop()
        assert rv is self, 'Popped wrong app context.  (%r instead of %r)' \
            % (rv, self)
        ctx.appcontext_popped.send(self.app)

    ctx.AppContext.pop = pop
```